# Updating multiple SQLite rows given columns and data

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'd like to be able to update multiple SQLite database rows given a list of columns and a list of lists of data. I have a working solution, but it's not elegant at all. How can I do this more efficiently. I've left out the actual `UPDATE` statement as I am just focusing on building the query.

```
def update(columns, values):
    for value in values:
        print ("Update myTable SET " + " ".join([x + ' = "%s",' for x in columns]) + ' WHERE SSN = "%s"').replace(", WHERE", " WHERE") % (tuple(value))

columns = ['Name', 'Age']
values  = [['Jon', 12, '545-45-7987'], ['Sam', 13, '454-78-4545']]

update(columns, values)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be interpolating values for your `UPDATE`; rather you should be using placeholders and query parameters. This will avoid quoting complications and potential SQL injection vulnerabilities. Something like:

```
def update(cursor, columns, values):
    for value in values:
        sql = "UPDATE myTable SET {} WHERE ssn = ?".format(
            ", ".join(map("{} = ?".format, columns)))
        print(sql)
        cursor.execute(sql, values)      

columns = ['Name', 'Age']
values  = [['Jon', 12, '545-45-7987'], ['Sam', 13, '454-78-4545']]
cursor = conn.cursor()  
update(cursor, columns, values)
```

Comment: Thank you. Much cleaner!

Comment: One comment. I think `SQLite` uses `?` as a placeholder rather than `%s`

Comment: @user2242044 Then why did you use %s in your question?

Comment: @Cubic: `%s` in the question is not a placeholder; it's a conversion specifier for the python's [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) operator `%`.